# Ignore manual entries from Apple Health app as Data Source

Tags: ios, healthkit

Hi I'm writing a Fitness App which gets its Data from Apples Health app.

So far so good.

Problem: in Health app it is possible to make manually data entries which makes it possible to cheat.

Question: how can i exclude or ignore this specific Data Entries.

> > Just the Data with "Source: Health" so i've still the possibility to read data from a random Fitness tracker.

Comment: You could basically use HKQuery to limit the search to certain app, look at this method on HKQuery + (NSPredicate *)predicateForObjectsFromSource:(HKSource *)source;

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Samples in HealthKit that were manually entered by the user will have have a YES value for the `HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered` metadata key.  To create a predicate that matches only samples that were **not** user-entered, you could do use the following:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"metadata.%K != YES", HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered];
```

Note that this must be formulated as `value != YES` because the value for the key could be YES, NO, or nil and nil implies NO.

Answer (score 20):

Swift 4:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "metadata.%K != YES", HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered)
```

And if you have two predicates, useCompoundPredicate:

```
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])
```