# Is it possible to detect the resource of the step count on HealthKit on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, healthkit

There are 2 ways to get step count on iPhone. The first is from actual walking, then iPhone detects the steps. The second one is that a user manually add step data.

Is it possible to find out  on HealthKit that the steps come from iPhone but not from a user input?

Comment: The answer is in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/31254817/5718382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "metadata.%K != YES", HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered)
```

Applying above predicate should help.

In case of objective - C

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"metadata.%K != YES", HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered];
```